# Django manage.py runfcgi doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I try to configure nginx + python + django.

My software: Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3, django 1.3.1 and flup. Also I have django project cloned from git repository to /var/www/myproject.dev.

Now I am trying to execute the following command from the root of my project:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080
```

and it shows:

```
ImportError: No module named myproject.dev
```

Why does it search for myproject.dev module and try to import it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: project's folder name contained `.` (dot) and django tried to explode it into two parts (`myproject` as `dev`). I removed dot from the folder name and everything is ok now.